# Stroing large entry in redis using cli?

Tags: redis, command-line-interface, redis-cli

I am trying to store data of 5000 characters in redis via cli.

My command is `SET MY_KEY "copy pasted the value"`

But the whole value is not getting pasted in CLI.
Is there any alternative to it.

I have redis version `3.0.54`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But the whole value is not getting pasted in CLI. Is there any alternative to it.

Yes, here is one which works with most modern shells: create a text file with your command(s) and use input redirection.

For example, create a file named *commands.txt* with your Redis commands:

```
SET MY_KEY "copy pasted the value"
```

And pass it to the CLI through input redirection (Bash here, but the syntax is similar if not equal in most modern shells):

```
redis-cli < commands.txt
```